# T4 POCO Generation with Inheritance bug - Derived Class won't generate in client side

Tags: wcf, silverlight-4.0, entity-framework-4, poco, t4

I've made a simple EF4 model with inheritance. Entity B derives form Entity A.
I am using the T4 POCO Template. (VS 2010)

In my Silverlight client, when adding service reference to the WCF Service, only the base class gets generated in the service namespace. The derived class is ignored.

This bug is mentioned here: http://forums.silverlight.net/p/157316/352167.aspx
but the link in the answer doesn't lead anywhere.

The solution mentions you can workaround this by adding some attributes. Or alternatively, is there an official bug fix ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a bug. It is common behavior. Your service operation returns the base class so the service description knows only the base class until you instruct it to use derived types as well. The most common solution is using `KnownType` attribute on your base class or `ServiceKnownType` attribute on service or operation. Another solution (in WCF4 is using `DataContractResolver`) - [MSDN magazine contains nice article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598929.aspx) about data contract inheritance.

Comment: Thanks ! adding the KnownType attribute on the base class solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an example of KnowType attribute

http://www.freddes.se/2010/05/19/wcf-knowntype-attribute-example/

Comment: Please can you summarise they key points of this article in your answer, in order for it to still make sense should the URL cease to work at some point in the future.